# nestjs process.env.variable is undefined in my auth.module.ts

Tags: nestjs

im trying to test jwt auth in nestjs.

when i called jwtService.sign();
it shows error secretOrPrivateKey must have a value - {}
secret is undefined.

but in AuthController, porcess.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY is work.

i dont know why it is not work.

how can i fix it ?

auth.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [AppConfig, MySqlConfig, OracleConfig],
      envFilePath: `${process.env.NODE_ENV}` == '' ? '.env.dev' : `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
      validationSchema: Joi.object({
        NODE_ENV: Joi.string()
          .valid('dev', 'stg', 'prd'),
      }),
    }),
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, Logger],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
       secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '1d' },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy, LocalStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

main.ts

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    bufferLogs: true,
  });
  app.enableShutdownHooks();
  app.useLogger(app.get(MyLogger));

  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  const logger = app.get(MyLogger);
  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('nestjs-tst-boilerplate')
    .setDescription('The nestjs-tst-boilerplate API description')
    .setVersion('0.0.1')
    .addTag('tag')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);

  await app.listen(configService.get<number>('app.port'));
  logger.log(`Application running on [${configService.get<string>('app.env')}] enviroment. ${await app.getUrl()}`);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the time that `process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY` is read, the .env might not be parsed yet. Thus, don't rely on `process.env.` if you're using some module like `@nestjs/config`. Use the async version of `JwtModule.register` instead and inject the `ConfigService`. See: https://github.com/nestjs/jwt/blob/master/README.md#async-options